# Giving function for more uiSwitch tags

Tags: ios, tags, uiswitch

I would like to set that if all of my switches for sender tag 0-6 will be off, app shows alert with warning message to put at least one of the switches on. I am now little bit lost with logic how to.

```
if (switi.tag ==0 && switi.isOn == YES )
    { [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
}else        if ((switi.tag ==1 && switi.isOn == YES)) {
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

        } else if ((switi.tag ==2 && switi.isOn == YES)) {
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

        } else if ((switi.tag ==3 && switi.isOn == YES)) {
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

        } else if ((switi.tag ==4 && switi.isOn == YES)) {
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

        } else if ((switi.tag ==5 && switi.isOn == YES)) {
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

        } else if ((switi.tag ==6 && switi.isOn == YES)) {
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

        } else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please put at least one switch on." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];

        }

}
```

EDIT

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



 CGFloat y = 110;
                int counter = 0;
                for (NSString *key in self.kejsss) {
                    UILabel *labeli = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, y, 150, 30)];
                    UISwitch *switi = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210, y, 70, 30)];

                    labeli.tag = counter;
                    switi.tag = counter;

                    labeli.text = key;
                    labeli.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    switi.on = [[self.konfiggg objectForKey:key] boolValue];
                    [switi addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                    [self.view addSubview:labeli];
                    [self.view addSubview:switi];

                    self.viewtabulka.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
                    self.viewtabulka.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
                    CALayer *imageLayerRR3 = self.viewtabulka.layer;
                    [imageLayerRR3 setCornerRadius:5];
                    [imageLayerRR3 setBorderWidth:1];
                    [imageLayerRR3 setMasksToBounds:YES];
                    y += 40;
                    counter++;

        }
        }
    }
}
- (IBAction)switchChanged:(UISwitch *)sender{
    kokos= YES;
    [self.konfiggg setObject:@([sender isOn]) forKey:[self.kejsss objectAtIndex:sender.tag]];
    NSLog(@"Selected Switch - %ld (%@)", (long)sender.tag, self.kejsss[sender.tag]);
    NSLog(@"Selected object - %d", [sender isOn]);
}
```

Comment: For starters DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself): create a function for repeated code. In this case there is a better algorithm, see the Answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.  Group all of your switches together in an array for convenience.  Then whenever one of the switches changes value, call a method that loops through all of the switches in the array and checks to make sure at least one is still on.  You could do it like this:

```
-(void)checkSwitches {
    // self.switches is an NSArray that holds pointers to all of your UISwitches
    for (UISwitch *s in self.switches) {
        if (s.on == YES) {
            return;
        }
    }
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please put at least one switch on." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: You could link them to IBOutletCollection instead of an NSArray if using Interface Builder.

Comment: Could you check my edit? I have still no idea, how to do that.

Comment: Create a NSMutableArray (self.switches) right before your for-loop in your viewDidLoad method.  Inside the for-loop, add each switch to the mutable array ([self.switches addObject:switi]).